# Porting a script that displays one record at a time from perl to php

Tags: php, perl

I have this perl script that selects and displays one record at a time

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from bar");
/*
bar has 50 records
*/
$sth->execute();
while(my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()){
print "Current Row is: id = $ref->{'id'},city = $ref->{'city'} \n";
print "_"x(30) . "\n";
 sleep(10);
}
$sth->finish()
```

with a sleep of `10` seconds.

In php,i am looking for a database independent way of accessing `next` and `previous` records instead of writing that code myself like for next `select * from foo where id = (select min(id) from foo where id > 1)`

How can i begin to port this code?.

Answer (score 1):

I ported it this way

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=odesk', 'root', '123456');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT job_description from le_jobs_content");
$sth->execute();
while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo $result['job_description'] .PHP_EOL;
sleep(3);
}
?>
```